# Can't set ctrl+shift combination as a shortcut to switch language

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Fedora and the latest KDE. I want to set ctrl+shift as a shortcut to switch keyboard language, but it only allows me to set ctrl+shift+some_other_key and any other combination e.g. alt+shift but not he one I want. I tried to do it in system configuration menu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of luck. The `xkb` has a predefined set of possible hotkeys. If it does not have the desired combination - the only way to do it is rebuild the `xkb`.

...or just use on the available hotkeys.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it.